# What is kernel and Assembler and how they are different to each other?

Tags: assembly, kernel

What is the difference between kernel and Assembler, and how they Work?
Is Assembler a part of kernel?

Comment: Refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33793506/os-kernel-applications-and-assembly#:~:text=1)Assembly%20is%20the%20language,functions%20that%20the%20OS%20uses.&text=(Like%20if%20you're%20trying,or%20function%20(JS%20background).

Comment: one has nothing to do with the other, one is a program the other is a language tool.

Comment: no doubt that a kernel in the typical use of that word in software context will have a relatively small amount of assembly language code as you very often need target specific instructions which the high level language cant magically figure out for you.   But the ratio is way less than 1%.  one line of asm to between tens of thousands and millions of lines of high level code.

Comment: the assembler is an application that you run, just like a web browser, pdf viewer, etc.  It is not part of the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

A kernal is a program that manages your computer, while giving you a user interface to run and load other programs such as spreadsheets, web browsers and pdf viewers.

An assembler is a program that takes a text file written by an assembly language programmer and converts the text mnemonics into machine language, either to be run directly or stored in an object file to be linked in with more code later.